# Thread and BufferedReader

Tags: java, multithreading, io, bufferedreader

I have a problem when I want to use multithreading to act as a Keyboard Listener.

So i write these code.

```
private static boolean out=false;

public static  void main(String[] args)
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            try{
                reader.readLine();
                reader.close();
            }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            out=true;
            System.out.println(" have received the keyboard");
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            while(true)
                if(out)
                    break;
            System.out.println(" exit the loop");
        }
    }).start();

}
```

But when I input something in console, it seems that the second Thread can not run.

If my code or expression is unclear or wrong , please tell me.

THANK YOU!
`

Comment: Where do you change `out`? (It also needs to be `volatile`).

Comment: Am I just mistaken or have you never assigned `true` to `out`? in this case the while loop will run forever.

Comment: sorry, i forget to add "out=true" . But it still can't work

Comment: Then Kayaman already delivered the solution. add `volatile` to the declaration of your variable `out`.

Comment: Short, to the point, and highly recommended: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd thread is already running as soon as you execute the program but since you have not assigned a new value to your variable `out` the `if`-clause will always and infinitly evaluate to `false` and therefore never break.
You can fix this by assigning `true` to out and make it `volatile` so that alaways the most recent updated value will be used. Try something like this:

```
private static volatile boolean out = false;

  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    new Thread( new Runnable()
    {
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ) );
        try
        {
          reader.readLine();
          // will only be executed after input since BufferedReader.readLine() is blocking.
          out = true;
          reader.close();
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println( " have received the keyboard" );
      }
    } ).start();

    new Thread( new Runnable()
    {
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        // added to show that the 2nd thread started.
        System.out.println( "Thread 2 started running...." );

        while ( true )
          if ( out )
            break;
        System.out.println( " exit the loop" );
      }
    } ).start();
  }
```

Comment: thank you ! but i also have a problem, if i remove the BufferedReader and its func , and I only set "out=true" in 1st Thread   ( the "out" is not "volatile"  ),  and the 2nd Thread can work! i am confused with it .    If you are busy , you can only offer some key word and I  will google it.

Comment: @梁子宏 just read a bit more about [volatile](http://www.baeldung.com/java-volatile) and multithreading in general. "volatile marka variable to be kept in the main memory" if you let the thread sleep for like 3 millis it won't work again without the the `volatile` keyword. A more precise explanation would go to deep for now.

Comment: the answers help me a lot ! THANK YOU!